# Query function logic, columns summing and grouping

Tags: function, google-sheets

Can someone please explain a few pretty basic questions for me about the query function.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b3heo-gvvyRwdE5yX11edq_IzSXbXSAxsYjb8EGeHAU/edit#gid=843005893
Why I can use star to select all columns

```
=QUERY('Your Jira Issues'!A:S,"SELECT * ",1)
```

but cannot use

```
=QUERY('Your Jira Issues'!A:S,"SELECT *, Q * (1-F)  ",1)
```

and is there any way to avoid of using this approach?

```
=QUERY('Your Jira Issues'!A:S,"SELECT A,B,C,E,D,F,G,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S, Q * (1-F)  ",1)
```

And the second part, this formula works as long as I am not grouping results `

```
=QUERY('Your Jira Issues'!A:S,"SELECT I,Q * (1 - F) ",1)
```

The moment results are grouped, I get an error

```
=QUERY('Your Jira Issues'!A:S,"SELECT I,SUM(Q * (1 - F)) GROUP BY I ",1)
```

error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "*" "* "" at line 1, column 17. Was expecting: ")" ...

Comment: Did you try "GROUP BY I" ( Capital I instead of 1) ?

Comment: thank you! I did, it was supposed to be an I instead of 1.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to pre-process the data before the query. Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Comment: added a copy of a gsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your last question, try

```
=QUERY(QUERY('Your Jira Issues'!A:S,"SELECT I,Q * (1 - F) ",1), "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 <>'' GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2)'SUM'")
```

or pre-process the data before querying

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({'Your Jira Issues'!I2:I, 'Your Jira Issues'!Q2:Q * (1 - 'Your Jira Issues'!F2:F)}, "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 <>'' GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'Assignee', SUM(Col2)'SUM'"))
```

See if that helps?

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Is there a work around for this =QUERY('Your Jira Issues'!A:S,"SELECT *, Q * (1-F)  ",1)?